# SharpDX Does Texture.FromMemory require that that the memory location not be changed after the texture is created?

Tags: c#, c++, directx, sharpdx

So I was having memory address space issues using bitmaps (or so I think based on my reading), and so I wanted to use one memorystream for the largest size image and just reuse it when creating all the textures I need.

However, upon completing the loop and using the textures to draw, it appears as if all the textures contain the same texture, which makes me think that I am not allowed to reuse the memorystream. Does creating a texture from memory just make the texture point to that memory location?

i'm really confused, and I wish I knew exactly what was happening in Texture.FromMemory(device, byte[]) and Texture.FromStream(device, stream).

I also don't know what usage to use when calling Texture.FromMemory(device, byte[], Usage, Pool).

Usage is defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb322805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

but I really don't understand what usage I should be using as the parameter when using that method signature. Usage.None results in nothing displayed. Usage.Dynamic results in an insufficient storage space, and Usage.WriteOnly gives another cryptic error.

Heaven knows what usage is actually being used as the default when I call the shorter two parameter method Texture.FromStream(device, stream).

```
      MemoryStream BitmapStream = new MemoryStream();
      for (int y = 0; y < OriginalBitmap.Height; y += MaxHeight)
      {
        for (int x = 0; x < OriginalBitmap.Width; x += MaxWidth)
        {
          Bitmap NewBitmap = OriginalBitmap.Clone(RegionToClone, OriginalBitmap.PixelFormat);
          Bitmaps.Add(NewBitmap);

          BitmapStream.Position= 0;
          NewBitmap.Save(BitmapStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

          BitmapStream.Position = 0;
          Texture t = Texture.FromMemory(device, BitmapStream.GetBuffer());
```

Comment: This is DirectX 9, right? Don't mix it up with DX11. You linked to DX11 `Usage` documentation. The default value for DX9 is `D3DX_DEFAULT`. The `FromStream()` does basically what you already did. It reads the stream and then uses `FromMemory`. See [the code](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Direct3D9/Texture.cs).